# Avoiding for loop and making function call only once by any user

Tags: solidity, contract-development, transactions, contract-design

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.17;
//  I want to write a code for  loyalty points when user pays 
contract GiveRefreceId {

    struct  referenceids {
        uint256 rid ;
        address addressrid;
}
    mapping(uint256 => referenceids) referenceid;
    referenceids[] lenrefrenceid;

function giveRefrenceId() public returns (uint256)  { 
    for (uint256 i=0 ;i<=lenrefrenceid.length; i++){

        require( lenrefrenceid[i]  != msg.sender);
    } 

    uint256 lenvarble = lenrefrenceid.length;

    referenceids  storage temprid = referenceid[lenvarble];

    temprid.rid = lenvarble;
    temprid.addressrid = msg.sender;
    lenrefrenceid.push(temprid);
    return lenvarble;
}

function  getrefrnceId()  view returns(uint256) {

return ((lenrefrenceid.length)-1);

}
}
```

1)I have written a function to give reference id's  to the user's

2)I want to restrict the user to call only once the `giverefrenceid` function  so i taught of  writing for loop and  check the address is present or not in the Array

3)but i am getting error

```
Operator != not compatible with types struct GiveRefreceId.referenceids storage ref and address
        require( lenrefrenceid[i]  != msg.sender);
```

4) I know it is complaining that struct and require coudn't be used but i coudn't find any other option to check

5)The gas will be costing more if the numbers increase Any way to avoid for loop,and  check the user is calling the function for the first time

6)I don't want to write two functions i want to get id by using one function is there any way ?

Comment: could you describe what this code should do? I mean the main functionality. This looks overcomplicated, you have a struct, a mapping of those structs, and also an array of the same structs.

Comment: Hi jame first thanks for your response 

I am trying to give a refrence id to user  and i want to use  that refrence id to give some loyality points in the next part of code for time   being i taught giving refrence id with the length of the array would be good so that i can get the address of the refreer person and give loyality points  and  i want to restrict the function to be called only once by any user

Comment: See my answer and let me know.

Comment: No it is not working  plese see the following link

https://remix.ethereum.org/#optimize=true&version=soljson-v0.4.25+commit.59dbf8f1.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code below should do.

The function `giveReferenceId` assigns an id to a user based on the address. The array `clients` save a list of users (just in case you need that list at some point).

To be sure that the same address only gets one id, the line: `require(referenceid[msg.sender]==0);` is used, as 0 is an invalid Id, meaning that the user is not registered.

The function getrefrnceId() return the id of the user that executes the function.

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.25;

contract GiveRefreceId {

    mapping(address => uint256) public referenceid;
    address[] public clients;
    uint256 idcounter;

    event createdId(address user, uint256 id);

    function giveRefrenceId() public returns (uint256)  { 
        require(referenceid[msg.sender]==0);
        idcounter += 1;
        clients.push(msg.sender);
        referenceid[msg.sender] = idcounter;
        emit createdId(masg.sender,idcounter);
        return idcounter;

    }


    function  getrefrnceId() public view returns(uint256) {
        return referenceid[msg.sender];
    }
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Sorry it is not working with same id  i am able to create 2 refrence ids 

https://remix.ethereum.org/#optimize=true&version=soljson-v0.4.25+commit.59dbf8f1.js

Comment: you mean with the same address you can register two different Ids?, this is no possible. Also, I run this in remix, if you try to execute giveReferenceId twice with the same address the transactions revert

Comment: No i want the user must call  Give refrence id function() only once he shouldn't be able to call it twice

Comment: You seem to be confused. You can not prevent the user from calling the function, what you can do is to reject the call by reverting if the subject already has called it, such that he/she doesn't create two different ids with the same address, and this is exactly what the contract does.

Comment: Thanks john  i  want same functionality 
what you can do is to reject the call by reverting if the subject already has called it, such that he/she doesn't create two different ids with the same address, and this is exactly what the contract does

But just see the transcations on etherscan  with same address i called 3 times the function and generated  2 ids

Comment: https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/tx/0xa5a0d2faaf1629930657dfd0acf94acb65396e3d4f7e65c2bd154c4e1f482716

https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/tx/0xcf11abe61b09588d739b328508d8959494a2a37f1dd38edcebbeefb4752972d2

https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/tx/0xf69a6ca1ffd88814175e5b6abd35ce93f80cb4dcf450340e72ed1b99d8ca30d5

Comment: give me the address where you deployed the contract

Comment: 0x0dd87fe70e4ed0af92f656396e9b7949aeb33cfc

Comment: Hey, the contract that you deployed is not the contract that I posted in my answer, what contract is this?

Comment: Sorry i worked with the previous transcation instance

Comment: No problem, those things happen, if this solved your question please accept the answer.

Comment: can you plese explain these line of code 
require(referenceid[msg.sender]==0);
 
and how to read the data from logs without writting second function

Comment: referenceid is a mapping, by default the values are set to zero (0). In this case if I mapp the user address the value returned is zero if the address has not been registered, so the require ask if the mapping avlue is zero and if not, it cancell the execution without assigning a new id. What do you mean by "how to read the data from logs without writting second function?", what data? there is a second function `getrefrnceId()` that returns the id of the user that calls it. is that what you mean?

Comment: Sorry james for length discussion 

Can we see the id without writting    getrefrnceId() function

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/85140/discussion-between-jaime-and-md-venkatesh).